# VScode: 'updating intellisense' forever

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I vscode on my Ubuntu 16.04 platform and I've installed `C++ Intellisense
austin.code-gnu-global` and `C/C++ ms-vscode.cpptools` extensions for cpp project. Here is a part of my setting.json:

```
"C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default",
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
"files.exclude": {
    "**/build": true,
    "**/.git*": true,
    "**/.vscode": true,
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true
},
```

The flame icon has alerted since yesterday. BTW, my project contains a large number of files which exceeds the maximum watchers `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`, So I wonder how can I cope with the warning:`"Visual Studio Code is unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace" (error ENOSPC)`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried raising the maximum watchers? It may be related to disk speed. I have the same issue but I am working on a huge codebase. Make sure you have "Limit symbols to included headers" checked and that you have a good "Intelli Sense Cache Size". Workspace parsing priority can also be set to "highest".